# Reciprocity theorem with $n \ge 5$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod n$, what additional conditions are needed to ensure that
$$2^{(p-1)/n} \equiv 1 \pmod p?$$

I know:

- For $n=3$  (cubic reciprocity) the form is $p=x^2+27y^2$.
- For $n=4$ (biquadratic reciprocity) the form is $p=x^2+64y^2$.
- The solution has to deal with Gaussian integers and Artin's reciprocity theorem.

Can someone please show me how exactly to do this, maybe with the example $n=5$.

Comment: I found it very hard to understand the question, so I re-phrased it, hopefully without changing the meaning.  Feel free to revert or re-edit if I did not succeed.  I *think* you also mean to assume that $p$ is prime.  I also mention your earlier question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362187/which-prime-numbers-fit-into-my-equation-similiar-to-fermats-little-theorem , which was the case $n = 3$.

Comment: If $n$ is a prime and $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ has class number 1, then you can use [Eisenstein reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_reciprocity) to give a similar criterion.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you read the excellent and very complete book of Franz Lemmermeyer (who is on MO) on the subject.